# SugarCRM 6.5 Password reset

Tags: sugarcrm

I replaced the admin password with one that was md5 and now I can't reset the password. it seems to be mcrypted. Does anyone have an idea how to gain access again to sugar?
E-Mail is not working.

Comment: Where did you replace the password at?

Comment: I replaced the users table with one of a 5.5.4 installation directly via sql: "REPLACE INTO `657`.`users` SELECT * FROM `554`.`users`;"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run the following against the Sugar database to reset the admin password to "test" then login and reset your password.

```
update users set user_hash = '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6' where user_name = 'admin';
```

Comment: nice guess :-) but it's encryption changed from md5 to a real one. I think it uses a salt. I'm diving into the code now to see how it is done and where the salt comes from

Comment: You should still be able to put in an MD5 password in there and it work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is correct. So my login problem has another cause.

Answer (score 4):

If the database is MySQL, you can easily set the password to whatever you like by using the built in md5 function:

`update users set user_hash = md5('mynewpassword') where id = '1';`